# Anyone know how to achieve this "lift" effect?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, hover, jquery-animate

I was looking at the [story page](http://www.teehanlax.com/story/teehan-lax/) of the new Teehan + Lax site and saw this sweet effect on the [hover of these images.](http://d.pr/i/23Dq) (You have to scroll down almost to the bottom of the page). Anyone know how easy this would be to implement? Or if there's a plugin out there that does something similar?

Thanks!

Comment: add a class with transform and shadow and animate it on hover.

Comment: Just look at the page source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.tl-site #making-tl .card .front:hover {
    transform: rotateX(10deg);
}
.tl-site #making-tl .card .front {
    transform-origin: 8px 8px 0;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition-duration: 0.75s;
```

Answer (score 0):

it is

```
-webkit-transform: rotateX(10deg);
-moz-transform: rotateX(10deg);
-o-transform: rotateX(10deg);
transform: rotateX(10deg);
```